Modern CV Error message: moderncvcolors.tex not found
I bought a new computer, installed Miktex and Texmaker.
When I tried to update my CV using moderncv, I ran the file and recived the following error message:
! LaTeX Error: File `moderncvcolors.tex' not found.
Does anybody know what the problem is and how can I solve it?
The log file says that I am using Document Class: moderncv 2024-07-18 v2.4.1

the filename changed at the last release check miktex has the full update see https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv/issues/136

@DavidCarlisle as the class requests the file but it is missing, it must be a packaging error. I opened an issue https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/439

Thank you Ulrike. The problem has been fixed.
